# Running k6 script for load tests returns an error

Tags: redirect, request, k6

I'm first time user of k6 and I've already manage to get an error when running the script:

> "Request Failed [33merror[0m="Get https:///: stopped
>   after 0 redirects"

Script k6.js:

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { sleep } from "k6";

export let options = {
 stages: [
    { duration: "30s", target: 20 },
    { duration: "1m30s", target: 10  },
    { duration: "20s", target: 0 },
  ]
};

export default function() {
  let res = http.get("https://<our_page_URL>/");
  check(res, {
    "status code MUST be 200": (res) => res.status == 200,
  }) || fail("status code was *not* 200");
  sleep(1);
}
```

Why do I get this error and what is the solution?

Comment: Why do you have the `|| fail()` check, instead of setting `options.throw` to `true`?

Comment: Good question. I found this example on the k6 page and seemed useful to me and that is why I used it to see how does it work. Unfortunately I don't know how to use options.throw, but will look into the docs.

Comment: @Sander & jurijk I think the docs were written before options.throw existed. Thanks for pointing this out, I'll see if I can update the docs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up the `maxRedirects` option; `maxRedirects` is the maximum number of HTTP redirects that k6 will follow before giving up on a request and erroring out with ("Get $PATH stopped after $MAX_REDIRECT_VALUE redirects")

You can pass the option as CLI argument or script options. More about this option at [https://docs.k6.io/docs/options](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/k6-options/reference/)

```
export let options = {
    // Max redirects to follow (default is 10)
    maxRedirects: 10
};
```

The default is 10, so there is likely a bug skipping the default value being assigned.

This is a [redirect example](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/blob/master/samples/redirects.js) to test how it works.

```
import http from "k6/http";
import {check} from "k6";

export let options = {
    // Max redirects to follow (default is 10)
    maxRedirects: 5
};

export default function() {
    // If redirecting more than options.maxRedirects times, the last response will be returned
    let res = http.get("https://httpbin.org/redirect/6");
    check(res, {
        "is status 302": (r) => r.status === 302
    });

    // The number of redirects to follow can be controlled on a per-request level as well
    res = http.get("https://httpbin.org/redirect/1", {redirects: 1});
    console.log(res.status);
    check(res, {
        "is status 200": (r) => r.status === 200,
        "url is correct": (r) => r.url === "https://httpbin.org/get"
    });
}
```

Comment: ppcano: this saved my day! Thank you! Now I finally have no error and the rest works flawlessly.

Comment: @jurijk: Happy to help. I thought you had already solved the issue after the Slack conversation, that's why I did not reply the question earlier.
Anyway, let us know if you have any question or need help. 

I also open a github issue for the bug https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/369